# False positives in PMD eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

Eclipse 2019-09, Java 11.0.5, PMD plugin 4.8.0

```
@Test
public final void testValueOf() {
    final String message = "Colour Object correctly set?";
    assertEquals(diamond, QCardColour.valueOf('d'), message);
    assertEquals(heart, QCardColour.valueOf('h'), message);
    assertEquals(spade, QCardColour.valueOf('s'), message);
    assertEquals(club, QCardColour.valueOf('c'), message);
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        QCardColour.valueOf('B');
    }, message);
}
```

PMD eclipse plugin marks the assertEquals with `JUnit assertions should include a message` which obviously is wrong. Gradle pmd plugin, working with the same ruleset.xml, shows no errors. How do i get rid of those messages without deactivating the rule?

Edit: The error shows up only in one project. In at least two other projects where assertEquals is in use, everything is fine.

Comment: This sounds like [PMD issue 1009](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1009) which has been fixed some time ago. Do you have the latest PMD plug-in? There are [more than one PMD Eclipse plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/pmd) which you might try.

Comment: @howlger: pmd-eclipse-plugin 4.8.0, Oct 31th 19, pmd 6.19.0. Should be the latest version. And did run for a year without problems. But perhaps i should try another plugin. Thank for the list.

Comment: PMD 6.19.0 should contain the fix for JUnit 5. [The rule just checks if `assertEquals` has three parameters and if the first (JUnit 4) or third (JUnit 5) parameter is a String; the JUnit version will not be detected](https://github.com/djydewang/pmd/blob/c1306659fbdda79215ad313363028b78d9eadcc8/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/bestpractices/JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessageRule.java). So I have no idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: @howlger: Seems to be a plugin problem, not a problem of pmd itself. I changed to eclipse pmd, the first plugin in the list you linked to, and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like [**PMD issue 1009**](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1009) which has been fixed some time ago. PMD 6.19.0 should contain this fix. The fix makes [the rule](https://github.com/djydewang/pmd/blob/c1306659fbdda79215ad313363028b78d9eadcc8/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/bestpractices/JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessageRule.java) less strict to handle both, JUnit 4 (where in `assertEquals` the message is the first parameter) and JUnit 5 (message is the third parameter).

It's unclear why you're running into this issue with the pmd-eclipse-plugin 4.8.0 as it should contain [PMD 6.19.0](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/blob/4.8.0.v20191031-1916/pom.xml#L19) with the fix for JUnit 5. You might [report the issue to the pmd-eclipse-plugin team](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/issues). There is [more than one Eclipse PMD plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/pmd) that you might use, at least until the issue is fixed.